# Pars multi level json by gson (okhttp)

Tags: android, json.net, gson, okhttp, multi-level

I have multi-level JSON like that.

```
 {"countries":[
    {
        "name":"USA",

        "grandfathers":[
            {
                "gFName":"Steve",
                "grandfathersKid":[
                    {
                        "gFKName": "Linda",
                        "kid": [{
                            "name": "Steve JR", 
                            "friends": [{
                                "name": "Kriss|John|Martin|Steven"
                            }]
                        }
                        ]
                    }

                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

how can I pars it with 'GSON'?
I use Okhttp for get data from server.

Comment: Use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org to create models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Class Countries{
  List<Country> country;
}

Class Country{
  String name;
  List<Grandfather> grandfathers;
}

Class Grandfather{

   String gFName;
   List<Kids> grandfathersKid;

}

Class Kids {
  String gFKName;
  List<Name> kid;

}

Class Kid{
  String name;
  List<Person> friends;
}

Class Person{
  String name;
}


// String to Object
Gson gson = new Gson();
Countries countries = gson.from(yourJsonString,Countries.class);
```